# Rotate the camera while driving along the path

Tags: rendering, camera

[image]How to make it so that simultaneously with the movement of the camera along the path, it rotates around the axis of this very path. I drew a small illustration.I hope quite clearly.

I use Blender 2.8

Comment: you can make it follow a path, and the camera itself can have its own keyframes in the dopesheet, in your case along its Z axis

Comment: as moonboots said, and then just check "Follow Curve" in the Follow Path Constraint

Comment: Also, if you enable Follow Curve on the Follow Path Constraint then it will follow the 'Tilt' of the path ('Tilt' is available in the properties side panel while in Edit mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it follow a path with a *Follow Path* constraint, and the camera itself can have its own keyframes in the Dopesheet, in your case along its Z axis.